# Symfony 2 Move validation to the Entity, Validation with related entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, validation

I have Appeal Entity; SiteTariff, User Entities; Tariff, Site Entities
How to move validation to the Entity. Validation complicated: with related Entities. I was trying to write a callback (at the Entity) => without result.

```
    $appeal = new Appeal();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($appeal);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        $appeal->setUser($user); //addRelation

        $appeal->appeals_count = $value; //set value to public field

        if ($site_tariff_id = $form->getData()->site_tariff_id)
        {
            $siteTariff = $em->find('', $site_tariff_id);
            $appeal->setSiteTariff($siteTariff); //addRelation
        }
        else
        {
            //addError, break
        }                      


        if ($appeal->getSiteTariff()->getSite()->getUser()->getId() != $user->getId())
        {
            //addError
        }

        if ($appeal->getSiteTariff()->getTariff()->getAppealsNumber() <= $appeal->appeals_count)
        {
            //addError
        }

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em->persist($appeal);
        }
    }
```

At callback I did not get $siteTariff object after calling `$this->getSiteTariff()`, symfony writes "**non-object**"

```
    public function isSiteTariffValid(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        var_dump($this->getSiteTariff()->getId());    
    }
```

Comment: I am not a symfony expert but is the line "$siteTariff = $em->find('', $site_tariff_id);" correct ? $em refers to your entity manager or your repository ? ($em->getRepository(entity)->find($id))

Comment: what is the current class and it's parent? Because i think `getSiteTariff()` is a method of an entity, not a validation class.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation code should be inside your entity and not inside your controller. Please refer to the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html